# Hashing of timestamp

Tags: hash, timestamp

I need a hash function(maybe I should not call that a "hash" function) that:

1.is used for hashing timestamps only;

2.there exist **a reverse function** that I can restore the timestamp through that function;

3.does not generate duplicate hash value;

4.whether not it is a hash function, it is nearly as fast as a hash function;

PS: About the data type of timestamp --- image that as a 4 bytes "long" type in C.

Is that possible?

(I need the timestamp to be a **secret**. --- In fact, I need the hash value as a session id and the original timestamp as an index in my database. Whenever user request something with the session id, I can get the timestamp as an index to get the request info.)

Comment: Maybe I just don't get it, but if you need a reverse function, it's not really a hash function. If you want to be able to reverse it, you must not lose information, so you can just stick with the timestamp itself.

Comment: Ah, I think that is an important aspect of your problem and you should include that in the question. I still think that "hash" is the wrong term here and I would suggest some simple XOR, but that is not very secure and others may have better ideas.

Comment: @Sentry Yes, I realize that is not actually a hash function :] I'm wrong. But I will not correct it here as I think it provides the intuitive meaning and I explain the actual meaning below that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can skip #2 MurmurHash might be a good option:

https://sites.google.com/site/murmurhash/

(2) If you must crypt/decrypt there are standard implementations of the various algorithms for most languages (AES, for instance).  This will be much slower than hashing.

If you don't actually need this to secure the data (which begs the question: why bother at all with any conversion?) and just want to make some non-timestamp-looking string that is easily reversible (by you -- and anyone else) then check this question:

[Rot13 for numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809137/rot13-for-numbers)

Comment: eh, I explained why I need the reverse function above again in the last paragraph.